# Object inheriting from EventEmitter does not raise events

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I am new to Node.js and am having trouble debugging an issue.  I have created an object which acts as an event emitter, however, my callbacks don't get called when the event is emitted.

I have defined my emitter as follows:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

// this is the object which will inherit from EventEmitter
function RequestStreamReader() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}
util.inherits(RequestStreamReader, EventEmitter);
module.exports = RequestStreamReader;

RequestStreamReader.prototype.read = function(req) {
    var data = '';
    req.on('data', function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        this.emit('readComplete', data);
    });
};
```

The code that consumes this module is listed below. The handler for my "readComplete" event does not execute despite the fact that `this.emit(...)` is called in the emitter (I have verified this in the debugger).

```
var Reader = require("../utils/requestStreamReader.js");

var reader = new Reader();
reader.on('readComplete', function(data){
    var userData = JSON.parse(data);
    var newUser = userModule.createFromDto(userData);
    userRepository.create(newUser, onSuccess, onFailure);
});
reader.read(req);
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that "this" is not what you think it is in your code where you try to call `this.emit('readComplete', data)`. In that context "this" refers to the callback function not the enclosing object. You need to do:

```
RequestStreamReader.prototype.read = function(req) {
    var data = '';
    var self = this;
    req.on('data', function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        self.emit('readComplete', data);
    });
};
```

You can even see the same technique at work inside of the actual source to node.js itself: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L80

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I suspect this isn't the only time I'm going to run into problems caused by the `this` keyword.

Comment: Pretty good overview here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this